# Is there a way to pause using PHPUnit extending Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-server

My tests are running too fast, and the code always fail. Is there a way to pause?

I tried $this->pause('3000'); and $this->wait('3000'); but it doesn't work.

Right now, I'm using $this->setSpeed('3000'); but it's running too slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need to wait a fixed amount of time: [Sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function will work as you would expect.

But better solution is to [wait for elements/text to be visible](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait#elements-visibility-and-invisibility) - the test will be able to resume work almost immediately after an HTML element is ready.

Comment: Thanks! My test cases run much faster now

Answer (score 2):

Use setSpeed(300) it is reasonable speed to see what is happening on the screen